# D3 data join() calls enter instead of update

Tags: d3.js, observablehq

I would like to update the cell values of name and rating based on the data that is selected by the input. Whenever the input changes the new values are entered but the update and exit functions are not triggered (values do not turn green or red). Any idea what I am doing wrong? A live version of the code can be found here:

https://observablehq.com/@nvelden/table-merge

```
const div = d3.create('div')
.style('display', 'flex');
const columNames = ["name", "rating"];

let headColumns = div
.selectAll('div')
.data(columNames)
.enter()
.append('div')
.text(d => d)
.attr('id', d => `Head-${d}`)
.attr('class', 'headColumns'); 
  
let names = div.selectAll('#Head-name')
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(dataInput(dataSelect), d => d.name)
  .join(
    enter => enter
  .append("div")
  .text(d => d.name)
  .style('opacity', 1),
   update => update
  .style('color', 'green')
  .style('opacity', 1),
    exit => exit
  .style('color', 'red')
  )
  .attr('class', 'cell');
  
let ratings = div.selectAll('#Head-rating')
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(dataInput(dataSelect), d => d.rating)
  .join(
    enter => enter
  .append("div")
  .text(d => d.rating)
  .style('opacity', 1),
   update => update
  .style('color', 'green')
  .style('opacity', 1),
    exit => exit
  .style('color', 'red')
  )
  .attr('class', 'cell');
```

Data

```
data1 = [
  {name: "Chocolate",rating:10},
  {name:"Jam",rating:9},
  {name:"Sprinkles",rating:8},
  {name:"Honey",rating:5}
];

data2 = [
  {name: "Jam",rating:20},
  {name:"Chocolate",rating:9},
  {name:"Sprinkles",rating:8},
  {name:"Honey",rating:7}
];
```

Data function

```
function dataInput(input){
  if(input == "DataSet 2"){
    return data1
  } else{
    return data2
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the current running snippet matches your [ObservableHQ](https://observablehq.com/@nvelden/table-merge) situation?

Comment: @Ruben Helsloot Yes it is the latest version

Comment: Rolled back because the behaviour was not present in the snippet

Comment: @Ruben Helsloot The snipped worked for you? The color changes to green for the updated values? It is not working on ObservableHQ

Comment: Yes, on SO it was, might be because of the select module, which I was not able to use anywhere outside of ObservableHQ. You can access previous versions of the code by clicking on "edited x hours ago"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ObservableHQ specific. The problem is that whenever the data input changes the entire code is triggered re-attaching the main div

```
const div = d3.create('div')
.style('display', 'flex');
```

The solution is to separate it from the rest of the code and put it in it's own block. See answer posted on the ObservableHQ forum:

https://talk.observablehq.com/t/data-join-calls-enter-instead-of-update/4109/3